# wix programmatically connect a table to a product page

Tags: javascript, json, velo

Hello I have made a web store using the Wix platform and I am having an issue connecting my custom coded table to a product page. The way I have it is the customer can search the products by title and the results populate a table with custom fields. The issue I am having is I want the customer to be able to click on a row and that will navigate them to the product page displaying the product they have clicked. here is my table in JSON object form which I got from the API docs and replace my own properties (works fine):

```
$w('#table1').columns = [{
        "id": "col1", // ID of the column for code purposes
        // The field key in the collection whose data this column displays  
        "dataPath": "mainMedia",
        "label": "Image", // The column header
        "width": 100, // Column width
        "visible": true, // Column visibility
        "type": "image", // Data type for the column
        // Path for the column if it contains a link  
        "linkPath": "link-path-or-property" //<this is what the doc says
    },
    {
        "id": "col2",
        "dataPath": "name",
        "label": "Name",
        "width": 350,
        "visible": true,
        "type": "text",
        "linkPath": "this is where I should have a link I think but what link"
    }, {
        "id": "col3",
        "dataPath": "formattedPrice",
        "label": "Price",
        "width": 100,
        "visible": true,
        "type": "text",
        "linkPath": "ProductPageUrl"
    }, {
        "id": "col4",
        "dataPath": "sku",
        "label": "SKU",
        "width": 100,
        "visible": true,
        "type": "text",

    } //,
    // more column objects here if necessary
    // ...
    // ...  
];
```

Then I use the built in function for my click event:

```
export function table1_rowSelect(event, $w) {
    //Add your code for this event here: 
    console.log(event.rowData); //It does read the correct item clicked


}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right direction. Yes, `linkPath` is where you put the link to the product page. (You could also use the rowSelect event with `wixWindow.to()`, but you don't need to do both.) Now all you need to do is figure out the correct path to use in `linkPath`.

Looks to me like you're using a Wix Stores collection for your row data. If so, when setting the table columns, you use the field key (not field name) of the field that contains the link. So for the product page, use `productPageUrl`. Note, that this is per column. So if you want each cell to be a link, you have to add the `linkPath` to every column.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I figured that I needed to use "linkPath": "productPageUrl", but when I click on the row it just scrolls to the top of the current page instead of navigating to the product page and that's where I am having a problem.

Comment: @RobertJohnson, maybe you can share more of your situation - code and maybe even a link to your site. I've tested the above on one of my pages and it works fine.

Comment: its centslescoins.com

Comment: @RobertJohnson, the only table I see is on the home page and there is no code there. Looks like you hooked up that table to show a larger view of the image.

Comment: Yes Sir. you are correct. I changed the design to display the selected item to the right in a larger view. That image should be linked to the product page. As you can see in the bottom left corner that the embedded link is displayed but it's not navigating to the page. If you right click and open link in new tab it does open the correct item in the product page. I don't understand why it will not click to open. Annoying. lol.

Comment: @RobertJohnson, I'm guessing that you're doubling (or tripling) up with what happens when the image is clicked. If you set the image link in code, you shouldn't set it using the link panel or using an onClick event handler. Pick one way and stick with it.

Comment: Thank you @Sam. Yes I was doubling. It woks now.